# Previous and next object in a large Django queryset

Tags: django, django-views

I have a model like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
    public = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

And a view (simplified):

```
def article(request, id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)
    
    data = {
        'article': article,
    }

    return render(request, 'articles/article.html', data)
```

This works fine. Next, I tried to add the buttons for the previous and the next article, using Django's get_previous_by_FIELD and get_next_by_FIELD:

```
def article(request, id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)
    
    try:
        previous_item = article.get_previous_by_date_created(public=True)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        previous_item = None
      
    try:
        next_item = article.get_next_by_date_created(public=True)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        next_item = None
    
    data = {
        'article': article,
        'previous_item': previous_item,
        'next_item': next_item,
    }

    return render(request, 'articles/article.html', data)
```

In principle, this works as well. But there is an issue with the performance. Without the previous/next buttons SQL queries are executed in under 50 ms. With the previous/next buttons, it takes over 2000 ms. The problem is that there are about 500.000 articles in the database (imported from RSS feeds so the number is increasing fast).

Does someone have an idea on how to implement the previous/next object functionality in a different, more efficient way?

EDIT:
From django/db/models/base.py:

```
def _get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD(self, field, is_next, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            raise ValueError("get_next/get_previous cannot be used on unsaved objects.")
        op = 'gt' if is_next else 'lt'
        order = '' if is_next else '-'
        param = getattr(self, field.attname)
        q = Q(**{'%s__%s' % (field.name, op): param})
        q = q | Q(**{field.name: param, 'pk__%s' % op: self.pk})
        qs = self.__class__._default_manager.using(self._state.db).filter(**kwargs).filter(q).order_by(
            '%s%s' % (order, field.name), '%spk' % order
        )
        try:
            return qs[0]
        except IndexError:
            raise self.DoesNotExist("%s matching query does not exist." % self.__class__._meta.object_name)
```

Comment: Can you add the `get_previous_by_date_created` and `get_next_by_date_created` methods to your question

Comment: @IainShelvington: these are automatically created by a `DateTImeFIeld`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO

Comment: What if you add a `db_index=True` to the `DateTImeFIeld`, so `date_created = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, I wasn't aware of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely the delay is caused by a lack of a database index, such that the database needs to iterate over all objects to find the next or previous one.

By using a database index, searching through the objects by `date_created` should be faster. You can also add a combination of `public` and `date_created` as index:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['public', 'date_created'])
        ]
```

You need to run migrations in order to construct the index at the database side.

You furthermore can try to manually create a query, with:

```
previous_item = Article.objects.filter(
    public=True, date_created__gt=article.date_created
).order_by('-date_created').first()
next_item = Article.objects.filter(
    public=True, date_created__lt=article.date_created
).order_by('date_created').first()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Willem. Added db_index=True to date_created, made migration, migrated. The execution times are now in the 1600-1700 ms range. Your suggestion definitely had an impact, but it's still quite slow.

Comment: @apiljic: you can also add a combined index (see edit), and make the queries yourself.

Comment: I tested several approaches, including adding additional filters to reduce the size of the queryset. With db_index=True and django method, the fastest I got was in the 150 ms - 200 ms range. The manual query you described I tried before and it was not faster than the django method. Now, with db_index=True, it is much faster, about 70 ms in my case, which is great I think. That's the approach I'll go for. Thanks a lot Willem! I really appreciate your help.